# Is it a bug in chrome about images load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, web, promise

My aim is to load some images using `style['background-image']` in html, But when I put my code in Ajax, there are something wrong.
If i use **async ajax**, the images load **order is reverse**; while i use **sync ajax**, the images load **order is normal.**
Especially,it happened in chrome.It's normal in firefox.

html structure is very simple like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

When i use sync ajax, the JS code like this

```
function Ajax(url) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                let slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test'))
                for (let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                    slides[i].style['background-image'] = `url(/data/gallery/1125425/content/${i})`
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open('get', url, false)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        xhr.send()
    }
    Ajax('https://api.github.com')
```

And the result is this[image]

We can find it's normal and just like what we think it should be

Howerver, when **change the async from false to true**,the result is like this.

To show the url doesn't matter this phenomenon, I use a public API by github.
And now we see the result in the network panel
[image]

We can see the last image is loaded first, just a reverse order compared with our first try.

In fact, this phenomenon won't happen in firefox, so i guess is it a bug in chrome?

I've put my code into [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Messiahhh/pen/OxrGBM?editors=1010).
**UPDATE:** **i thought lt's caused by Promise, after then i noticed it's not. So i change the title**

Comment: Wow, this is really weird, but this seems like a problem that needs debugging, would you be able to add Codepen or similar so we can debug?

Comment: I know it's just an example, but you should start counting at i=0 so you don't miss the first element.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I've update and put code into Codepen, If you're going to debug this, you can just change the image url

Comment: @GrafWampula thanks, I've edited it. It's because i constantly changed my code to test what happen.

Comment: Does `axios` use native promises? But yes, this is weird in either case.

Comment: "so i guess is it a bug in chrome" --- for something to be a bug there should be a standard that requires any particular behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging your codepen, I found out that any kind of scope wrapping reverses the order. This one:

```
  let slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test'))
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   (() => slides[i].style['background-image'] = `url(/data/gallery/1125425/content/${i})`)();
  }
```

And this:

```
(() => {
  let slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test'))
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style['background-image'] = `url(/data/gallery/1125425/content/${i})`
  }
})();
```

**So the Promise has nothing to do with**, I guess.

But also I would say that the forward order (in my case) is not strict forward order, it is buggy: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 8, 7, 19, etc` and this sequence does not change from time to time during a session.

Comment: Thanks for answer,but i found your code won't reverse the order. And the Promise has nothing to do with as what you said, I think it's caused by the ajax 'async'.You can see my update in the question description

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a bug per se, even if still weird.

This happens because the browser won't recalculate the styles of your elements during this `for` loop, but only after the js execution has ended and all the DOM changes have been made.

What happens in the next steps (style recalc -> loading of new resources) is up to the implementation.

If you want a fixed order <sub>(even if I don't see why you would)</sub>, you can force a reflow at every loop iteration:

```js
(() => {
  let slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test'))
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style['background-image'] = `url(/${i})`
   document.body.offsetWidth; // force reflow
  }
})();
console.log("check the 'Network Panel' of your dev-tools");
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```